# Stream output to String

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-10-universal

So I want to serialise a class which contains an `IReadOnlyList<InkStroke>` from `Windows.UI.Input.Inking`, as I'm working on a UWP app.

I'm using a `DataContractSerializer` to serialise my class, however I need to serialise the IReadOnlyList first, to a `string` or `byte[]`, so that it can be serialised with the `DataContractSerializer`.

The most appropriate method of saving the strokes from a `StrokeContainer` is the `StrokeContainer.SaveAsync()` method, which takes in an `IOutputStream`.

How can I create an `IOutputStream` and then capture the output as a `string` or `byte[]`?

Below is the method I am trying to implement this functionality to:

```
private async Task<string> SerializeStrokes(InkCanvas canvas)
{
    IReadOnlyList<InkStroke> currentStrokes = canvas.InkPresenter
                                                    .StrokeContainer
                                                    .GetStrokes();

    if (currentStrokes.Count > 0)
    {
        string serializedString = string.Empty;

        using (IOutputStream outputStream = somethinghere)
        {
            await canvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.SaveAsync(outputStream);
            await outputStream.FlushAsync();
        }

    // use some kind of stream reader to return contents of output ?
    }
    else
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can return a base64 string for the stream is binary.

The first is save it to stream

```
        var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        await canvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.SaveAsync(stream);
        await stream.FlushAsync();
```

The last is change stream to base64

```
        var buffer = new byte[stream.Size];
        await stream.AsStream().ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
```

Comment: So having implemented this code you suggested, I discovered that, regardless of what is on the canvas, the buffer is always a `byte[]` full of 0s, and therefore the string is always "AAAAA...", and hence the data is not successfully written to a string. Any ideas?

Comment: It appears that the line `await stream.AsStream().ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);` does not write anything to the `byte[] buffer`

Comment: I think I forget set the `stream` Seek to 0

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I couldn't for the life of me figure out what it was!